# Homebrew formula for Play 2.1 RC2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, homebrew

**QUESTION**

Is there a homebrew formula for Play 2.1 RC2? I've been tried searching on google, but no luck. Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

I think I got it. I found the formula for RC1, and modified it to create one for RC2. I'm testing it right now. Here're the contents of play.rb I create on my local machine.

```
# Recipe for play-2.1-RC2

require 'formula'

class Play < Formula
  homepage 'http://www.playframework.org/'
  url 'http://download.playframework.org/releases/play-2.1-RC2.zip'
  sha1 'cd25571250b753cec81e916059025465e541637d'
  version '2.1-RC2'

  def install
    rm Dir['*.bat'] # remove windows' bat files
    libexec.install Dir['*']
    inreplace libexec+"play" do |s|
      s.gsub! "$dir/", "$dir/../libexec/"
      s.gsub! "dir=`dirname $PRG`", "dir=`dirname $0` && dir=$dir/`dirname $PRG`"
    end
    bin.install_symlink libexec+'play'
  end
end
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've created a public gist for the above file. So, here's the final command you can use to install Play 2.1 *RC2*:

```
brew install https://gist.github.com/raw/4579402/play.rb
```

You may need to unlink the previously installed version of Play, using:

```
brew unlink play
```

**UPDATE 3**

As of today (2/3/2013), brew command suggested by Faruk is still installing RC2, and I wanted RC4. So here's the command to install Play 2.1 *RC4*.

```
brew install https://gist.github.com/raw/4705322/play.rb
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following command:

```
brew install --devel play
```

This will install the development version (which is play-2.1-RC2 as for now) instead of the stable version.

Comment: Thanks Faruk! I'm feeling so dumb now, having gone through all this pain of creating an independent formula file! Having said that, I think the gist I created will help someone trying to install RC2 specifically.

Let me try your suggestion. :)

Comment: When I do that command it just says "Error: play-2.0.4 already installed". Not quite sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can check latest version by:

```
$ brew update
$ brew info play
```

Or go to the formula file

```
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/play.rb
```